# Explain about Ergo Proxy and Proxy one and their relation with Monard Proxy

Tags: ergo-proxy

I just now finished Ergo Proxy and have few questions regarding it. Please Help

1) Who loved Monard Proxy initially? Proxy One or Ergo Proxy?

2) Who created Romdo? Proxy One or Ergo Proxy?

3) Why did Proxy One create Ergo Proxy in the first Place? And why did Ergo Proxy had his memory locked away? Was it according to some plan of Proxy One?

4) Which one was imperfect Proxy? Since the creator of Romdo is Considered imperfect?

5) why did the creator of Romdo fled it? whichever proxy it was?

thanks a lot :)

Comment: I haven't seen Ergo Proxy, but this question doesn't strike me as primarily opinion-based. If you're voting to close on that basis, it would be nice if you would leave a comment saying why.

Answer (score 5):

Ok so after thinking over this and reading some other stuff I believe the answers might be:

1. At first Proxy One loved Monad and Monad loved him back. Then Ergo was created, and as he was basically a Proxy One clone, he also loved Monad and Monad loved both as they were regarded as one.
2. Romdo was created by Proxy One, Romdo was most likely created before Ergo Proxy. (You could argue about it being also created [or co-created] by Ergo as the series discusses about identity and about Proxy and Ergo having the same persona, being one and the same, despite of them having 2 separate bodies. Proxy One regarded Ergo as a part of him and in turn he was a part of Ergo, he regarded both of them together as Proxy One and each separate body as a part of One, not a copy; Ergo struggled to define himself as a different entity.)
3. This is a very complicated topic, some argue Proxy One created Ergo so that Ergo could live the life Proxy One longed for without any knowledge of the Proxy Project. I believe it was to kill Monad. Proxy One loved Monad. Proxy One was the agent of death. He was destined to kill Monad. But he loved her. So he created a copy of himself who was appointed to carry his Proxy duty and kill Monad. But the copy, Ergo, also loved Monad, and Monad loved both Ergo and Proxy One. So Ergo decided to wipe his memory to avoid his destiny of killing Monad, and Monad helped him using the Amnesia autoreiv. Probably Proxy One left Mosk after he created Ergo, so he wouldn't witness Monad's death, but the plan failed as Ergo wiped his memory, then came Romdo's attack, Monad's kidnaping, and Vincent's migration to Romdo. When Proxy One came back, he found Ergo had failed his duty, and thus the story begins.
4. All proxies were imperfect as they were created by humans. The creator of Romdo was considered imperfect but it was never intended to be perfect. Proxies were created so they could create humans, but humans were imperfect from the start. So imperfect humans created imperfect Proxies to create more imperfect humans. What's the point on that? Why create more imperfect Humans to live on Earth if the original imperfect humans destroyed it in the first place? I don't know, ask Proxy One ;)
5. Proxy One fled from Romdo as he wanted to live with Monad whom he loved. He had issues with the overall raison d'etre of the Proxy Project which also conflicted with his proxy duties so he fled.

This are my interpretations, feel free to discuss/change/dismiss/adapt them to what the story meant to you. Although this questions about the events where the catalyst that led to the animated story, they are left unanswered and left to the viewers interpretation as their answers depend of the viewers understanding of the themes discussed (theology, identity, perfection, purpose, etc.)

Hope it helps :)